# MooTools 1.5.2 exploring typeOf and instanceOf

Tags: javascript, mootools

I decided to explore MooTools javascript core file to understand how such javascript frameworks work, unfortunately there are a lot of things in javascript that confuses me a lot because I don't know why particular function is made that way.

In the beginning of MooTools Core javascript file I see two functions: typeOf and instanceOf. I don't understand the purpose of these two lines of code:

```
var typeOf = this.typeOf = function(item){
var instanceOf = this.instanceOf = function(item, object){
```

Why function is assigned to typeOf variable and this.typeOf and why not just for var typeOf or just this.typeOf? And the same thing is with instanceOf.

I would be really grateful if anyone could explain why functions are assigned to variable and to global object what advantages can it give? I understand how it works but I simply can't understand why need to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `var typeOf = this.typeOf`  has 3 purposes. One is to work with a small variable name inside the file and avoid using `this.typeOf` all the time, second and more important is to avoid mixing up scope inside a scope where `this` is something else. The third purpose, using `this.typeOf` is to export it to the scope where you are, and MooTools exports to global, ie the `window` object in the browser for example.

The function `.typeOf` is [described in the docs](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.2/Core/Core#Core:typeOf) and you can see it as a more usable method than the native `typeof`. Look at these diferences:

in MooTools:

```
typeOf([]) // gives you "array"
typeOf({}) // gives you "object"
typeOf(document.createElement('div')) // gives you "element"
```

in Native JavaScript

```
typeof [] // gives you "object"
typeof {} // gives you "object"
typeof document.createElement('div') // gives you "object"
```

So MooTools gives a much more valuable result. Similar behavior can be found in [`.instanceOf()`.](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.2/Core/Core#Core:instanceOf)

Comment: Thanks! Now I can see how it can be useful in many ways. Definitely the most important thing that it does is that it avoids mixing up scope inside a scope.